# How to pass a hidden value from a html form to PHP without letting the user manipulate it?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, security

I am developing a forum like website using php and mysql. A user can ask a question and other users can reply to it. So my database table structure is like below.

Two tables questions and replies:

[image: Two tables questions and replies]

Now I have designed a page to view the question, replies and post another reply. So when I insert a row into replies table I have to pass the question id too. It can be simply achieved by passing the question id via a hidden element in the form. But this is not secure because a user can change the hidden value and the reply will end up in a wrong question.
Another solution is to use a session variable to store the question id the user is currently viewing. But this is also not possible because user could be opening multiple tabs which will cause problems with session variable.

So how do I solve this problem? I would really appreciate it if you could give me an idea.

PS - How do the famous forum sites solve this problem?

Comment: encrypt the id or place a message authentication that ties this to a particular form. Like all webdev, consider your web form inputs as untrustworthy.

Comment: Yes I could encrypt the id. But still it has to be stored in a hidden form element. So the user can still manipulate. (Perhaps he could decrypt the id too). Could you please explain what message authentication is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have another hidden element which has a hashed version of the id, on the backend check that the hash matches (the same way you check a password against a db, i'm assuming you know how this works but i can explain if you don't)

Why does it matter if the user edits the request to comment on a different question?
the only reason i can think of, is that some questions are restricted to allow none/certain comments, in that case the you should already be handling that in the backend.

as danblack commented, you should always assume user inputs are untrustworthy, you should always handle validation like this on the backend.

Comment: I could hash the id. But if a user figures that out he could change the both id and hashed id. So it will still end up in wrong question.    Yes there are restricted questions but I have handled that in the backend. The only problem is a user could change question id and it will end up in wrong place. It is a little bit faulty I guess.

Comment: how are you handling restricted questions on the backend? that's what will need to be fixed. as a general rule frontend validation is for the user's benefit (let them know they missed a field etc...) but backend validation is for your benefit, you should never rely on frontend validation for this sort of issue

Comment: Restricted questions mean, they can only be viewed by admins and the user who asked the question. When someone posts a reply to a restricted question I get the current user via session and checks if he is eligible to post the reply.

Comment: then run that check every time someone posts a comment anywhere, if it's an unrestricted question then the allowed users would be everyone. the restricted and unrestricted questions are using the same forms right?

Comment: But the problem here is, a user could change the id and that reply will end up in another public question.

Comment: but if the other question is public then they could simply go to that question and post the question there, so what is the issue if they post it from a different question? it is mpossible for this to happen by accident, so there's no usability issue. And since you're already handling the restricted questions on the backend there's no security issue either

Comment: But doesn't it feel like a fault? I just want to make that imposiible.

Comment: there are things you can do to make it more difficult, such as include a hashed hidden field, you could incude 15 fields each with different hash functions, or you could do it with an ajax request, but ultimately the browser is the users domain, if they have malicious intentions then they'll figure out a way to manipulate that request, no matter what you do. that's why you always have server side validation, because client side is always bypassable